# Building calendar. Overlapping scrollable content.

Tags: flutter

I am building calendar based app and trying Flutter.

Can you give advice/example of hierarchy how build complex and efficient layout like Google Calendar daily view?
Main question: how should I layout constant hours background and overlapping dynamic events layer?

I used RecyclerView and custom RecyclerView.LayoutManager before, but have no idea about Flutter way.

[image: Google Calendar daily view]

Comment: Were you able to finish implementing that using flutter?

Comment: Yes, it works well.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the code or give an overview of how you implemented it? Thank you.

Comment: I used CustomMultiChildLayout with [MultiChildLayoutDelegate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/MultiChildLayoutDelegate-class.html) There is good sample in docs.

Comment: it will be a great help if you share code, I am looking for similar kind of solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct your layout efficiently using [`GridView.custom`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.custom.html).

> A custom SliverGridDelegate can produce an aribtrary 2D arrangement of children, including arrangements that are unaligned or overlapping.

An easier option might be to use a [`CustomMultiChildLayout`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) but that will require laying out all the children instead of just the ones that are visible. It could be slower, but maybe that isn't the bottleneck for a calendar app.